# Why this resource couldn't find error message appear?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I am opening a downloaded project in to my netbeans IDE. When I try to build this project following error message is appeared.

```
C:\Users\mymachine_name\Downloads\StoreKeeper-master\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:1212:
 Warning: Could not find resource file
 "C:\Users\mymachine_name\Downloads\StoreKeeper-master\${libs.ControlsFx.classpath}"
to copy. BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

I tried to resolve this by adding this missing controlfx jar file, But it didn't work

> My project name - StoreKeeper-master

Comment: did you finally resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is netbean could not find some files to resolve it 
go to properties >Library and remove the red files

watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4Oez0o_XUI

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the project folder there is a folder named library which contains all external jar files used in the project. `Controlfx*.jar` is also found in it. Include this jar file in your project library, then remove the `ControlsFx` library in the project.